# quick questions on CompositeC1 Out of box features

Tags: c1-cms

I am doing research on which CMS to choose, have few questions wrt CompositeC1 CMS.

1. What is the Professional support Cost?
2. Installation Time
3. Does it offers in-context editing?
4. Does it offers DragnDrop content feature
5. Does it allows upload of audio & video files?
6. Image zoom feature?
7. eCommerce built in capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

1. [$265/Month](https://www.composite.net/Products/Plans)
2. 3 minutes.
3. No.
4. Can you elaborate? You can ie. [drag'n drop media](http://users.composite.net/Image-Media/InsertanImage) from your computer and into the content, which will then automatically be uploated and added.
5. [Yes.](http://users.composite.net/Image-Media/UploadaMediaFile)
6. [Yes.](http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/Resizing-Images)
7. No.